# Convert characters to binary?

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding, binary

I can get a binary representation of characters as follows:

```
BaseForm[ToCharacterCode["A"], 2]
```

> [image]

However, that produces a weird binary code object that might be nice to look at, but not very practical to work with. What I would like to extract from this is a list of digits:

```
{1,0,0,0,0,0,1}
```

Is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
IntegerDigits[ToCharacterCode["A"], 2]
```